# Nodejs referencing module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I'm trying to do some js code shared between the browser and the nodejs server. To do that, I just use these practises: http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/writing_for_node_and_the_browser/

The problem is when I want to export a function, not an object. In node you could do something like:

```
var Constructor = function(){/*code*/};
module.exports = Constructor;
```

so that when require is used you can do:

```
var Constructor = require('module.js');
var oInstance = new Constructor();
```

The problem is when I try to reference the module.exports object in the module and use that reference to overwrite it with my function. In the module it would be:

```
var Constructor = function(){/*code*/};
var reference = module.exports;
reference = Constructor;
```

Why this doesn't work? I don't want to use the easy solution to insert an if inside the clean code, but  i want to understand why it is illegal, even though reference===module.exports is true.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because `reference` does *not* point to `module.exports`, it points to the object `module.exports` points to:

```
module.exports
              \ 
                -> object
              / 
     reference
```

When you assign a new value to `reference`, you just change what `reference` points to, not what `module.exports` points to:

```
module.exports
              \ 
                -> object

reference -> function
```

---

Here is simplified example:

```
var a = 0;
var b = a;
```

Now, if you set `b = 1`, then the value of `a` will still be `0`, since you just assigned a new value to `b`. It has no influence on the value of `a`.

> i want to understand why it is illegal, even though reference===module.exports is true

It is not *illegal*, this how JavaScript (and most other languages) work. `reference === module.exports` is true, because before the assignment, they both refer to the same object. After the assignment, `references` refers to a different object than `modules.export`.